# Asp.Net Web API 2 model not automatically binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

Simple ApiController method:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public void TakeIt(MyObject o){
        Console.Write(o.ToString());
    }
}
```

Simple data type:

```
public class MyObject{
    public string V1{ get; set; }
    public string V2{ get; set; }
}
```

Simple post:

```
POST http://localhost:11026/api/test/takeit HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:11026

{"V1":"Something","V2": "Something else"}
```

For some reason the MyObject o will not automatically bind from the JSON form post body (even with `[FromBody]` inserted before the parameter on the method.

Am I doing something wrong?

**SOLUTION (DUH!)**

To debug my incoming requests, I had put this in my global.asax (because I was failing to get the requests to flow through Fiddler) so I could inspect them first

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        using (Stream receiveStream = Request.InputStream)
        {
            using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                var content = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(content);
            }
        }
    }
```

This was stopping anything down the line from reading the posted data. Soon as I removed that, the automatic model binding worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you either need to decorate your method with [HttpPost] or rename it to PostTakeIt.  Web API defaults to GET I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Two things

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void TakeIt([FromBody]MyObject o){
        Console.Write(o.ToString());
    }
}
```

Tag the action with `HttpPost` as is it not actually conforming to convention-based routing, and next tag the parameter with `[FromBody]` so the model binder know where to look for the model.

Also, given the URI `api/test/takeit` the assumption here is that the route template is `api/{controller}/{action}`.

The default template is usually `api/{controller}/`

```
// Convention-based routing.
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

which does not cater for the action name.

You would either have to add another route

```
// Convention-based routing.    
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

or use Attribute routing

```
// Attribute routing.
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

// Convention-based routing.
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

With updated controller

```
[RoutePrefix("api/test")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("takeit")] //Matches POST api/test/takeit
    public IHttpActionResult TakeIt([FromBody]MyObject o){
        Console.Write(o.ToString());
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have explicitly stated that I changed the API route mapper to "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}". Unfortunately neither adding [FromBody] to the parameter nor [HttpPost] to the method makes any difference to the binding on my controller. I have a feeling its a config setting somewhere that is missing.

Comment: @Jimbo I would have to agree. There is not enough info in the OP for use to tell though. provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem and help find a solution.

Comment: Dammit, knew it was something simple... I have put more info in my OP explaining why this wasnt working. Thanks for your efforts.